# Add case to file while Matlab GUI is running

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have a list with cases and would like to add another case while my GUI is running and save this case permanently to the code. Is there any method to implement this procedure?

```
function popupmenu7_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to popupmenu7 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: contents = cellstr(get(hObject,'String')) returns transducer_model contents as cell array
%        contents{get(hObject,'Value')} returns selected item from transducer_model

% Select transducer model and centre frequency (Hz).

val = get(hObject, 'Value');
str = get(hObject, 'String');
switch str{val}
    case '1MHz Sonic Concepts H198' 
        handles.centre_freq = 1e6;
        handles.transducer_index = 1;
        handles.fgen1_voltage = (handles.fgen1_PNP-31.767)/3.5411;
    case '0.5MHz Sonic Concepts H107' 
        handles.centre_freq = 0.5e6;
        handles.transducer_index = 2;
        handles.fgen1_voltage = (handles.fgen1_PNP*2-28.8)/6.055;

end

guidata(hObject, handles);
```

Comment: Probably the same method you got when you asked this question an hour ago.

Comment: To be fair this question is slightly different... but this time the answer is that dynamically changing your code in this way is difficult and not recommended, you need a different architecture.

Comment: Please read the tag information of tags you're planning to use. I edited [guide] to [matlab-guide] now for you. (double ping to be on the safe side)